# The generated war after the deploy, does not see the servlets

Tags: eclipse, maven, web, tomcat7, war

I generated two war files, one using export-> war file in Eclips second using maven-war-plugin. When I deploy this war in localhost tomcat7 or on an external server, the Tomcat application can not find the servlet. Links that point to servlets returns a 404 error

War is correctly deployowany because the home page is displayed correctly.

Eclipse does not show any errors in servlets so I say that's not the problem.

Deploy war directory structure looks like this:

```
 css, fonts, img, js, loess, META-INF, pages, WEB-INF (with epmpty controller folder and the folder lib with my jar eg. Mysql_connector). But nowhere I can not see the folders with my model
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I have several ideas, yes. The war could not be deployed. It could not contain the servlet. You could use an incorrect URL. The servlet code could be wrong, etc. etc. Without any detail in your question, we can't tell.

Comment: post web.xml  , and the link which return a 404 here .